# Recommended DB-solution for a JS-Driven FAQ page

Tags: javascript, seo, couchdb, angularjs, single-page-application

I would like to redevelop a large FAQs page in one of our website.

At the moment, the page is a static HTML document with all the (expandable) questions/answers pairs structured in a DL list, each list being a category.

However, this leads to SEO issues. I would like to find the best way to redevelop this section so that each question maps to a unique URL in Google.

This is a Java EE, Spring/Hibernate (Oracle in the background) application. However we do not want to use our Oracle DB to store the FAQs. We would like to keep this page as much client-driven as possible. I have read that single-page web apps are bad for SEO.

What are your recommendations, CouchDB, NoSQL, partials?
We are already using jQuery, AngularJS and Gson in the background.

Comment: This seems too broad and looks for opinions. Could this be re-worded to a more objective, fact-based question? Unfortunately, as it stands it's not a great fit for this site.

Comment: What do you mean by "client driven"? Do you want the client browser to do all the db-lookup and page-construction? Do you want the Q&As to be stored on the client and not on the server? I don't see much of a point in sending the entire FAQ database to the client(unless it's a downloadable FAQ...)

Comment: @IdanArye Indeed, I would like the browser to make the page construction using REST services. However, I do not see how to do that while ensuring good SEO

Comment: What if you make a (dynamic) page for each question, **in addition** to the main questions page? That way, users can access everything easily from the main page, and search engines can look at the specific question pages.

Comment: @IdanArye Excellent suggestion! I will need to store the FAQs in a DB then, would you recommend going for a NoSQL DB for such a scenario, I'm completely new to this NoSQL world so I don't know the pros/cons...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you implement the idea I wrote in the comments, I see no reason not to put the FAQ on your Oracle database - since you no longer need to transfer the database to the user.

If you still insist on not using your Oracle database, I would suggest not using a database, but saving the questions in an XML\JSON file instead.

If you need database capabilities, I usually recommend [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sqlite), but use whatever tool you know best.